# How do I grab only comments posted by current concrete5 logged in user?

Tags: comments, concrete5, userid

This code displays all comments by all members. How can I make this only show comments that the current logged in user posted?
I know this is simple code but for the life of me I can not seem to get it.
The code listed below is the original code from the view.php file located in the guestbook block.

```
<?php  $c = Page::getCurrentPage(); ?>
<h4 class="guestBook-title"><?php echo $controller->title?></h4>
<?php  if($invalidIP) { ?>
<div class="ccm-error"><p><?php echo $invalidIP?></p></div>
<?php  } ?>
<?php 
$u = new User();
if (!$dateFormat) {
$dateFormat = t('M jS, Y');
}
$posts = $controller->getEntries();
$bp = $controller->getPermissionObject(); 
$dh = Loader::helper('date');
foreach($posts as $p) { ?>
<?php  if($p['approved'] || $bp->canWrite()) { ?>
<div class="guestBook-entry<?php  if ($c->getVersionObject()->getVersionAuthorUserName() == $u-                >getUserName()) {?> authorPost <?php  }?>">
    <?php  if($bp->canWrite()) { ?> 
            <div class="guestBook-manage-links">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->action('loadEntry')."&entryID=".$p['entryID'];?>#guestBookForm"><?php echo t('Edit')?></a> | 
                <a href="<?php echo $this->action('removeEntry')."&entryID=".$p['entryID'];?>" onclick="return confirm('<?php echo t("Are you sure you would like to remove this note?")?>');"><?php echo t('Remove')?></a> |
                <?php  if($p['approved']) { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->action('unApproveEntry')."&entryID=".$p['entryID'];?>"><?php echo t('Un-Approve')?></a>
                <?php  } else { ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo $this->action('approveEntry')."&entryID=".$p['entryID'];?>"><?php echo t('Approve')?></a>
                <?php  } ?>
            </div>
        <?php  } ?>
        <div class="contentByLine">
            <!---<?php echo t('Posted by')?>
            <span class="userName">
                <?php 
                if( intval($p['uID']) ){
                    $ui = UserInfo::getByID(intval($p['uID']));
                    if (is_object($ui)) {
                        echo $ui->getUserName();
                    }
                }else echo $p['user_name'];
                ?>
            </span> 
            <?php echo t('on')?>--->
            <span class="contentDate">
                <?php echo $dh->date($dateFormat,strtotime($p['entryDate']));?>
            </span>
        </div>
        <?php echo nl2br($p['commentText'])?>
</div>
<?php  } ?>
<?php  }

if (isset($response)) { ?>
<?php echo $response?>
<?php  } ?>
<?php  if($controller->displayGuestBookForm) { ?>
<?php   
if( $controller->authenticationRequired && !$u->isLoggedIn() ){ ?>
    <div><?php echo t('You must be logged in for notes.')?> <a href="<?php echo View::url("/login","forward",$c->getCollectionID())?>"><?php echo t('Login')?> &raquo;</a></div>
<?php  }else{ ?>    
    <a name="guestBookForm-<?php echo $controller->bID?>"></a>

    <div id="guestBook-formBlock-<?php echo $controller->bID?>" class="guestBook-formBlock">

        <!---<h5 class="guestBook-formBlock-title"><?php  echo t('Leave a Reply')?></h5>--->
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo $this->action('form_save_entry', '#guestBookForm-'.$controller->bID)?>">
        <?php  if(isset($Entry->entryID)) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="entryID" value="<?php echo $Entry->entryID?>" />
        <?php  } ?>

        <?php  if(!$controller->authenticationRequired){ ?>
            <label for="name"><?php echo t('Name')?>:</label><?php echo (isset($errors['name'])?"<span class=\"error\">".$errors['name']."</span>":"")?><br />
            <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $Entry->user_name ?>" /> <br />
            <label for="email"><?php echo t('Email')?>:</label><?php echo (isset($errors['email'])?"<span class=\"error\">".$errors['email']."</span>":"")?><br />
            <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $Entry->user_email ?>" /> <span class="note">(<?php echo t('Your email will not be publicly displayed.')?>)</span> <br />
        <?php  } ?>

        <?php echo (isset($errors['commentText'])?"<br /><span class=\"error\">".$errors['commentText']."</span>":"")?>
        <textarea name="commentText"><?php echo $Entry->commentText ?></textarea><br />
        <?php 
        if($controller->displayCaptcha) {


            $captcha = Loader::helper('validation/captcha');                
            $captcha->label();
            $captcha->showInput();
            $captcha->display();

            echo isset($errors['captcha'])?'<span class="error">' . $errors['captcha'] . '</span>':'';

        }
        ?>
        <br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" name="Post Comment" value="<?php echo t('Save Note')?>" class="button"/>
        </form>
    </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every $posts ($p) is an array. When you print the array you will notice the ID of the author is present in the array.

If you'd like to show only the comments of the logged in user, you should override the view.php and replace line number 16

```
<?php if($p['approved'] || $bp->canWrite()) { ?>
```

to

```
<?php if(($p['approved'] || $bp->canWrite()) && $u->getUserID() == $p['uID']) { ?>
```

When you've changed that line of code, a user should only see his/her comments and not the comment of someone else.

Comment: Perfect! I did have to remove $u = new User(); for it to post the userID, but after that it did exactly what I needed.